# The English mathematician Augustus DeMorgan, who lived in the 19th century, once remarked that he was $x$ years old in the year x^2. When was he born?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

I found this from Elementary Number theory from Koshy. The answer is $1806$, but does know tell how to find?
Anyone have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Seeing that $40^2=1600$ and $50^2=2500$, we've narrowed it down to just $9$ possibilities.  Trying them all, the only one that yields an age in the $19th$ century is $43^2=1849$.  Thus, he was born in $1849-43=1806$.

Comment: Hint: $1900 \geq x^2-x\geq 1800$

Comment: @ZackNi: this bracketing expresses that he was *born* in the $19^{th}$ century (and the right inequality should be strict); it yields the two solutions $1806$ and $1892$; this is not quite the same as *lived* in the $19^{th}$ century, though this expression is ambiguous.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes that should be add this inequality and my original statment to a system of inequality(i.e. $x \leq 1900$)

Comment: @ZackNi: you probably mean $x^2-x\le 1900-a$, where $a$ is the minimum "allowed" age of death, which must be $\ge x$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry a typo. It should be ($x^2 \leq 1900$). The system of inequality is $x^2 \leq 1900$ and $1900 \geq x^2-x\geq 1800$. That's it.

Comment: @ZackNi: this is where the problem statement is ambiguous: it is not said that the constraint $x^2\le1900$ must hold. And if you interpret as "lived only in the $19^{th}$", the constraint $x^2\le1900$ does not guarantee that.

Comment: Yes so I hope that the one who issued this problem can clarify this statment.

Comment: I posted the problem as it have been written in the books not add or deleted any words.

Comment: Okay, I will stop splitting hairs, $1806$ is undisputably the right answer, but others are possible with a pinch of bad faith :)

Answer (score 4):

Living in the $19^{th}$ century means born somewhere between $1700$ and $1900$ (with a large safety margin, more than $100$ years lifetime). This corresponds to possible $x$ in range $\left\lceil\sqrt{1700\frac14}+\frac12\right\rceil=42$ to $\left\lfloor\sqrt{1900\frac14}+\frac12\right\rfloor=44$ inclusive.

$$\color{green}{42^2-42=1722,\\43^2-43=1806,\\44^2-44=1892}.$$

All three solutions are possible! As written, the problem statement doesn't really allow to reject $1722$, though he would have been aged $42$ in the $17^{th}$ century and needed to live at least $79$ years to reach the $19^{th}$, nor $1892$, though he would have been aged $44$ in the $20^{th}$ century (but still born in the $19^{th}$).

---

A stronger interpretation, "lived *only* in the $19^{th}$ century" (which happens to be true) restricts the range to $43,44$, and allows to rule out $1892$, as that birth year would imply that he died before the age of $9$.

---

The strange formulas come from

$$a\le x^2-x\le b$$
$$a+\frac14\le\left(x-\frac12\right)^2\le b+\frac14$$
$$\sqrt{a+\frac14}+\frac12\le x\le\sqrt{b+\frac14}+\frac12$$

Comment: Wow I've never this formula before ^ ^

Comment: @Fourier: they call it "completing the square".

Answer (score 3):

Assume the solution is a whole number.

Look at squares in between 1800 and 1900. As $40^2=1600$ trying the next few numbers shows $43^2=1849$ is in that range. That shows he must be born in year $1849-43=1806$.

Comment: Thank you very much for help me ^ ^